# Enumerating Features in a WSP or Deployed Solution using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am creating a build script that will automatically create a Test Site, Deploy all wsp to that site and activate all the features. The problem I have is how do I enumerate the feature Names or GUID's from the WSP's or from the Test site for the WSP's I have just deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop through the SPFarm.FeatureDefinitions and select all the ones where the SolutionId is equal to the added Solutions ID

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!